# gulp: работа с gulp.src и gulp.dest

Tags: gulp, gulp.dest

Файловая структура для поекта:

```
-root // корень проекта
  --app //папка для продакшена, в нее будут складываться компилированные файлы    
  --dev // папка для разработки, в ней будет вестись разработка
```

структура dev папки для scss:

```
-dev  
  --scss   
    --base // здесь подключаемые файлы, миксины, переменные....
    --components // папка со стилями для компонентов проекта 
      --component1  
        style.scss  
      --component2  
        .....  
   main.css
```

gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('dev/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'})) 
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 4 versions']
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
});
```

на выходе:

```
-app  
 --components  
  --component1  
    style.css  
   --component2  
    style.css  
main.css
```

так вот как сделать что - бы на выходе было следующее:

```
-app 
   --component1  
      style.css  
    --component2  
      style.css  
 main.css
```

пробовал в `gulp.dest` задавать колбек и в ней менять `file.relative`:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest(function(file) {
        var path = file.relative.split('\\');
        (path[0] == 'project components') ? path.shift() : path;
        file.relative = path.join('\\'); 
        return 'app';
    }))
```

В результате чего получил ошибку о невозможности модифицировать `file.relative`

> Error: File.relative is generated from the base and path attributes.
>   Do not modify it.

Правда не пробовал саму `path` модифицировать...
А вот при такой выборке:

```
gulp.src(['dev/scss/main.scss','dev/scss/project components/**/*.scss'])
```

Складывает как мне необходимо. Только бы вот еще ложил скомпилированные файлы в паку `css`...
Подскажите какие есть варианты и способы раскладывать скомпилированные файлы так как мне захотелось и те папки которые я укажу?

Comment: Попробуйте https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten

Comment: А почему бы не использовать [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename)?

Comment: @ Yaroslav Zaika, спасибо, посмотрю что за зверь, но хотелось бы разобраться  что да как....

Comment: @ Dmitriy Simushev, тоже как вариант.... С галпом только начал знакомиться, до этого пользовался грантом... так что смотрю что да как...